# SQL CommandText Confusion with double quotes and single quotes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on making a login system for my website. I am trying to make this code work.

```
cmd.CommandText="SELECT Usernames,Passwords FROM logininfo WHERE Usernames="" + UsernameInput.Text
        + "AND Passwords="" + PasswordInput.Text + '"";
```

My only problem is I am confused where to put the " and the ' types of quotes. So this is the code that I am having trouble with. I know it is correct but the single and double quote placement is confusing me and is not letting me compile.

Comment: You should not be storing passwords unhashed in a database for a website. There are many many tutorials out there that will teach you how to correctly store a password in a database.

Comment: That code is begging for a classic SQL injection attack!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't concatenate SQL, that exposes you to SQL injection.
Use parameters instead.

```
cmd.CommandText="SELECT Usernames,Passwords FROM logininfo WHERE Usernames=@username AND Passwords=@password";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UsernameInput.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordInput.Text);
```

Also take the advice in the comment of Scott Chamberlain, it is a bad thing to store passwords in clear or encrypted on a database. Just store hashes. But read about how to do it, it's not immediate (you need to salt it correctly and use a robust hashing algorithm such as SHA512).

It's far too complex to explain here but you'll find tons of guides on this problem.